# Is it possible to change the value of the field based on the the browser's language?

Tags: 8

On my Drupal 8 website I have a content type "Video" which has an "Embed Code" field. Later the user is able to watch the video inside the platform. The value for this field usually looks like this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/some_link" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Is there a way to change the source link based on the language of the browser? So for example when the user browser's language is set to "FR", then I would like to append to the emded link the french captions, so that the link looks following ?

https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/some_link?cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=fr

Answer (score 1):

This is the plugin what also core using for browser language negotiation. You can have a closer look what the plugin exactly does: `\Drupal\language\Plugin\LanguageNegotiation\LanguageNegotiationBrowser`

**The code**

```
$language_negotiation_method_manager = $this->container->get('plugin.manager.language_negotiation_method');
$plugin_id = LanguageNegotiationBrowser::METHOD_ID;
/** @var \Drupal\language\LanguageNegotiationMethodInterface $language_negotiation_method */
$language_negotiation_method = $language_negotiation_method_manager->createInstance($plugin_id);
$request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
$browser_langcode = $language_negotiation_method->getLangcode($request);
```

This will either give you back a valid language code or FALSE if the negotiation was unsuccessful.

**Regarding the dependencies**

1. `$container` is only used as an example to show which services are being used.
2. `Request` is always present as an argument when you are in a controller.

Comment: This, and `hook_preprocess_field` and probably also a custom cache tag to round it up. :)